# С каким языком программирования легче стать самоучкой Python или Java?

Tags: java, python

Всем привет. Я хочу стать программистом самоучкой. С каким языком программирования легче стать самоучкой Python или Java, с каким языком быстрее и легче начать работать на upwork.com? И с каким языком легче устроиться в компанию на junior программиста?

Comment: Из этих 2-х с первым

Comment: Можно и тот и другой рассматривать, все зависит от желания учиться.

Comment: Языки решают немного разные проблемы. Java используют практически только в энтерпрайз решениях. на Python пишут, начиная с дата саенса и заканчивая гейм индустрией. Например, world of tanks.

Comment: @Pro100Denysko, а android разработка куда подевалась?

Comment: Попробуйте оба. На вкус и цвет...

Comment: @Ivan ой, сам просто джавист, про андроид забываю иногда :)

Comment: С любым, главное - учитесь

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, это зависит от изучающего. Кому-то легче зайдёт Java, кому-то Python. Во-вторых, стоит избавиться от стремления к лёгким и быстрым путям, если цель - в конечном счёте стать профессионалом. В-третьих, шансов успешно работать на фрилансе почти нет у того, кто ещё не отработал пару-тройку лет в офисе и не дорос хотя бы до слабенького мидла. В-четвёртых, спрос на разные языки разный в разных регионах. Откройте работный сайт, вроде hh.ru, и посмотрите на какой язык больше джунских вакансий в вашем городе.

Comment: просто я живу в очень маленьком городе и там вообще нет работы программистом и хочу переехать в Санкт Петербург. Я зашел на яднекс.работа (он ищет с разных сайтов, в том числе hhr.ru) и junior python без опыта 2 вакансии в Питере, а java junior без опыта 4. Но брат мне говорит, что лучше Python (он общался с программистами и тим лидами). К тому же, как тогда устроиться на работу? Ведь даже на для junior нужен опыт и практика? Подскажите, где можно получить практику и портфолио на Python, чтобы можно было устроиться на работу в офис в Питер?

Comment: А разве, нельзя выполнять сначала очень простые заказы на Upwork на Python?

Comment: @МаксимСобко на вакансию джуниора опыт требоваться не должен. Вам нужно только хорошо знать теорию и демонстрировать желание работать. Хорошо, если ещё есть какой-нибудь пет-проект. Естественно, не стоит ждать, что вас сразу же возьмут. Конкуренция среди джунов очень высокая, на первое рабочее место придётся прорываться.

Comment: @МаксимСобко во-первых, одно из отличий джуна от мидла - неспособность работать самостоятельно, без надзора. Джуны, конечно, думают, что способны. В результате вы с высокой вероятностью либо неправильно оцените задачу и не сможете её завершить, либо породите продукт ненадлежащего качества. В обоих случаях получите негативный отзыв и карьера на UpWork закончится. Во-вторых, за очень простые заказы будет конкурировать 3-5 исполнителей с опытом, 20-30 таких же джунов, как вы, и ещё 100 индусов.

Comment: что значит пет-проект?

Comment: @МаксимСобко https://lsreg.ru/petproject/